# Directional derivate of a convex proper function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The subgradient at $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ of a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is any vector $g\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$f(y)\geq f(x) + g^T(y-x) \qquad\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$I have some problem about showing that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial d}:=lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(x+td)-f(x)}{t}=max\{g^Td\,|\,g\, \text{is a subgradient}\}$$

Comment: Let $g\in\partial f (x)$. Then,

$$f(x+td) \geq f(x) + \langle g, x+td-x\rangle = f(x) + \langle g,td\rangle\\
\implies \frac{f(x+td) - f(x)}{t} = \langle g,d\rangle$$

Comment: I did the same things but by this i show that the directional derivate is greater or equal than max $g^Td$. I don't understand why you can deduce that is equal, can you explain it to me?

Comment: It's a mistake, I meant to write $\geq$ indeed as you noticed. It was meant as a hint, that's why I didn't put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refer to a subgradient, you should say at which point otherwise it doesn't make sense. Thus, all "subgradient" instances in your question should be replaced by "**subgradient at $x$**".

Let me use the standard notation $f'(x; d)$ to denote the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in direction $d$:
\begin{equation}
f'(x; d) = \lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{f(x+td) - f(x)}{t}.
\end{equation}
We need to prove that
\begin{equation}
f'(x; d) = \max_{g\in \partial f(x)} g^T d \quad\forall x,d\in\mathbb{R^n}.
\end{equation}
This is a standard result in convex analysis and proofs can be found in any books on the topic. My proof below may be slightly different than those, in which I explicitly provide the subset of maximum solutions.

First, notice that
\begin{equation}
f(x+td) - f(x) \ge g^T(x+td-x) = tg^Td \quad \forall g\in\partial f(x), \forall x,d,t,
\end{equation}
we obtain
\begin{equation}
\boxed{f'(x; d) \ge g^T d \quad\forall g\in\partial f(x),\forall x,d.}\tag{*}
\end{equation}
We can prove the reverse inequality, or alternatively show that there exists $g\in\partial f(x)$ such that equality holds. To this end, we need some fundamental properties of directional derivatives:

1. $f(y) \ge f(x) + f'(x;y-x) \quad\forall x,y$.
2. The function $h(u) = f'(x;u)$ is convex and homogeneous of degree 1.

Both can be proved easily using the definition of $f(x;u)$ and the convexity of $f$.

Since $h(u)$ is convex, we have $h(u)\neq\emptyset$ and thus
$$h(v) - h(u) \ge g^T(v-u)\quad \forall v,\forall g\in\partial h(u).$$
If we choose $v=tu$ for some $t$, then $h(v) = h(tu) = th(u)$ and we obtain
$$(t-1)h(u) \ge (t-1)g^Tu.$$
Because the above holds for any $t$, we must have $h(u) = g^Tu$. Hence, we have proved that
\begin{equation}
\boxed{h(u) = g^Tu \quad\forall g\in\partial h(u), \forall u.}\tag{**}
\end{equation}
Using this equality and the above first property of directional derivatives, we get
$$f(y) \ge f(x) + f'(x;y-x) = f(x) + h(y-x) = f(x) + g^T(y-x) \quad \forall g\in\partial h(y-x), \forall y,$$
which implies $\partial h(y-x) \subset \partial f(x)\ \forall y$, or equivalently $\partial h(u) \subset \partial f(x)\ \forall u$. Therefore, we see that in $(*)$, equality occurs for any $g$ in the nonempty subset $\partial h(d)$ of $\partial f(x)$. QED